# How to loop over local storage removing elements with the same value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Assume that there are some data stored in local storage like:

- key  :  value
- item1:   1
- item2:   4
- item3:   2
- item4:   1
- item5:   4

and I want the result to be like:

- "item1: value 1 repeated 2 times"
- "item2: value 4 repeated 2 times"
- "item3: value 2 repeated 1 time"

and delete the similar value items

I am using js, html, css

Comment: for(let i=0;i<window.localStorage.length-1;i++){for(let j=i+1;j<window.localStorage.length;j++){ if(window.localStorage.getItem("Item"+i)===window.localStorage.getItem("Item"+j)){window.localStorage.removeItem("Item"+j)}}}

Comment: You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/EzioMercer/uv42pLje/